Calculating a surface integral of a surface by another surface
Let $\Sigma$ be the surface $\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2=1$, $0\leq z\leq 1$ and $u(x,y,z)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},z^2-z)$. Calculate the flux integral $\iint_\Sigma (u|N)dS$ where $N$ points away from the $z$-axis.
So the answer is $2\pi$. The flow out of $\Sigma$ is the same as the flow out of $x^2+y^2=1$, $0\leq z\leq 1$. I have absolutely no idea why this is the case. I would be very thankful if someone explained it to me.

Consider the interior of the surface and exclude a little cilinder of, say $x^2+y^2 < \varepsilon, 0\leq z\leq 1$, if you use divergence theorem you will see that the integral in your surface union with this cilinder with negative orientation will be zero, you can do the same in the case $x^2 +y^2 = 1, 0\leq z \leq 1$, so both flows are the same as the little cylinder, in fact, any cilinder with $0\leq z\leq 1$ will have the same flow

Apply the Divergence (Gauss’s) Theorem.

@RaulFernandesHorta But $u$ is not defined along the z-axis. The divergence theorem assumes there to be a top and bottom of a cylinder but they cross the z-axis

@perpersson that is why I said to exclude the little cylinder, so the $z$-axis won't be at the domain of integration

@RaulFernandesHorta but what about the top and bottom of the cylinder is the flux through them 0?

@perpersson I would have to compute that, but to use the divergence theorem you have to consider the whole closed surface

@TedShifrin the flux on top and bottom in the z-direction is 0 so there is only flux that goes out from the sides. That is condition for gauss theorem to work right?

Yes, because the $z$-component of the force vanishes at both top and bottom (where the normal vector is vertical), there is no flux out of the top and bottom.

As Raul Fernandes Horta has noted we should consider excluding a smaller cylinder. Remark: this is a common practice in such questions, some other examples include open bounded $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $u(\mathbf{\bar{x}}) = \frac{\mathbf{\bar{x}}}{\Vert\mathbf{\bar{x}}\Vert^3}$ possible solutions would be $0, 4\pi$ if origin is within $\Omega$ and not respectively. Another famous one is winding numbers to which your problem is closely related (by choice of vector field). Now to the solution:
Take $\epsilon = \{x^2+y^2 < \varepsilon, 0\leq z\leq 1
\}$ We also ignore the top and bottom as the flux is zero there when closed. We add the flux integrals but note that the smaller one has an induced opposite normal hence the minus.
\begin{equation}
\iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{N} \, dS - \iint_{\epsilon} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{N} \, dS = \iiint \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}) \, dV
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\iiint \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{u}) \, dV = \iiint 2z-1\, dV = 0
\end{equation}
Now we conclude the following:
\begin{equation}
\iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{N} \, dS = \iint_{\epsilon} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{N} \, dS = \iint_{\epsilon}  \, dS = 2\pi
\end{equation}
This shows that any cylinder $0<z<1$ around the origin will have a flux of $2\pi$, note that if it were shifted we would not have an issue with the z-axis, and then the flux is 0. Hope this helps! Varsågod.
